# Why I can't unlink photo in php

Tags: php

I want to unlink a photo file.

My file path will `../images/img.jpg`

So I write that code:

```
$path = "../images/img.jpg";
unlink($path);
```

Why it is not working and how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post path structure?

Comment: Is the path correct? Wrap a "file_exist('../images/img.jpg')" before your unlink and debug it.

Comment: I suspect a different between the relative path (i.e. the path you need to send to your browser for an `img` tag) and the absolute path, the path needed by your PHP code.

Comment: If unlink didn't work, you would have gotten an error. Share that error. If you don't see anything, turn on error reporting.